# Grupar/filtrar y hacer cálculos sobre líneas de una dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una dataframe con los artículos vendidos por diferentes tiendas todos los días:

```
    date    date_block_num  shop_id item_id item_price  item_cnt_day    day month_year
1953691 24.09.2014  20  5   1039    899.0   1.0 24  09.2014
1953692 27.09.2014  20  5   1015    449.0   1.0 27  09.2014
1953693 07.09.2014  20  5   1329    399.0   1.0 07  09.2014
1953694 27.09.2014  20  5   984 399.0   1.0 27  09.2014
1953695 08.09.2014  20  5   984 399.0   1.0 08  09.2014
```

Me gustaría obtener los resultados para cada tienda. Entonces intenté:

```
revenues = {}
for row in transactions_december_2014.sort('shop_id').iterrows():
    if last_shop_id == row.shop_id:
        revenues[shop_id] += row.item_price * row.item_cnt_day
        last_shop_id = row.shop_id
    else:
        revenues[shop_id] = row.item_price * row.item_cnt_day
print(max(revenues))
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-391a52cd0210> in <module>()
      9 # transactions_december_2014.groupby("shop_id").sum(transactions_december_2014.item_price * transactions_december_2014.item_cnt_day)
     10 revenues = {}
---> 11 for row in transactions_december_2014.sort('shop_id').iterrows():
     12     if last_shop_id == row.shop_id:
     13         revenues[shop_id] += row.item_price * row.item_cnt_day

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3079             if name in self._info_axis:
   3080                 return self[name]
-> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3082 
   3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Tambien pensia utilisar `groupby`s:

```
transactions_december_2014.groupby("shop_id").sum(transactions_december_2014.item_price * transactions_december_2014.item_cnt_day)
```

Pero nunca funciona. Pienso ahora hacer una cosa con `lambda` hasta que utiliso bucles for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Revolucion for Monica, creo que lo que buscas es obtener el revenue de cada shop_id ¿ es así ? entendiendo a revenue como: **p** (precio) * **q** (cantidad)

Mi sugerencia es primero calcular revenue en una nueva columna como:

```
df['revenue'] = df['item_price'] * df['item_cnt_day']
```

y luego realizar el group by:

```
df.groupby('shop_id')['revenue'].sum()
```

Si deseas agrupar por otro columna para conocer el revenue como item_id solo agregala en el group by, ejemplo:

```
df.groupby(['shop_id', 'item_id'])['revenue'].sum()
```

Suerte !